# CSS Issue on Mobile View for Circular Shopping Cart Element

Tags: html, css, wordpress, woocommerce, cart

I apologize for reaching out with an issue, but I'm struggling to resolve it on my own. I'm trying to create a circular design element above my shopping cart for the amount of product in the cart by making some CSS adjustments to my template. While it works perfectly on a computer, I'm encountering a problem on mobile devices. On phones, the circular element appears inside behind my cart, whereas on a PC, it's displayed as intended.

You can see the issue by visiting my website souksville.com and resizing the browser window to a smaller size.

Here's the CSS code I've used:

```
@media (max-width: 783px) {
  .navmenu {
    float: none;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 999;
  }
  .logo {
    margin-left: 20%;
    width: 40%;
  }
  .top-cart-row .dropdown-cart .lnk-cart {
    width: 40px;
    height: 45px;
    line-height: 15px;
  }
  .glyphicon.glyphicon-shopping-cart {
    margin-left: -12px;
  }
  .basket-item-count {
    margin-top: -15px;
    margin-left: -30px;
    z-index: 999;
  }
}
```

I would appreciate any guidance or suggestions on how to make this work consistently across both PC and mobile devices. Thank you in advance for your assistance!

update:

maybe it will help if I share also the header.html:

```
<?php
/**
 * header.php
 * @package WordPress
 * @subpackage Dealsdot
 * @since Dealsdot 1.0
 * 
 */
 ?>
 
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
<head>
    <meta charset="<?php bloginfo( "charset" ); ?>">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <?php wp_head(); ?>
</head>

<body <?php body_class(); ?>>
<?php wp_body_open(); ?>

<?php if (!get_theme_mod( 'dealsdot_loader' )) { ?>
<div id="preloader"></div>
<?php } ?>

    <header class="header-style-1">
        <?php $topheader = get_theme_mod('dealsdot_top_header','0'); ?>
        <?php if($topheader == '1'){ ?>
            <div class="top-bar animate-dropdown">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="header-top-inner">
                        <div class="cnt-account">
                            <?php 
                               wp_nav_menu(array(
                               'theme_location' => 'top-right-menu',
                               'container' => '',
                               'fallback_cb' => 'show_top_menu',
                               'menu_id' => '',
                               'menu_class' => 'list-unstyled',
                               'echo' => true,
                               'depth' => 0 
                                )); 
                             ?>
                        </div>

                        <div class="cnt-block">
                            <?php 
                               wp_nav_menu(array(
                               'theme_location' => 'top-left-menu',
                               'container' => '',
                               'fallback_cb' => 'show_top_menu',
                               'menu_id' => '',
                               'menu_class' => 'list-unstyled list-inline',
                               'echo' => true,
                               'walker' => new dealsdot_topleft_walker(),
                               'depth' => 0 
                                )); 
                             ?>
                        </div>
                        <div class="clearfix"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        <?php } ?>

        <?php if(get_theme_mod('dealsdot_sticky_header') == "on"){ ?>
            <?php $menutype = 'fixed-menu'?>
        <?php } else { ?>
            <?php $menutype = 'static-menu'?>
        <?php } ?>

        <div class="main-header <?php echo esc_attr($menutype); ?>">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-lg-2 col-sm-12 col-md-3 logo-holder">
                        <div class="logo">
                            <?php if (get_theme_mod( 'dealsdot_logo' )) { ?>
                                <?php $size = get_theme_mod( 'dealsdot_logo_size', array( 'width' => '176', 'height' => '37') ); ?>
                                <a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( "/" ) ); ?>" title="<?php bloginfo("name"); ?>">
                                    <img src="<?php echo esc_url( wp_get_attachment_url(get_theme_mod( 'dealsdot_logo' )) ); ?>" height="<?php echo esc_attr( $size["height"] ); ?>" width="<?php echo esc_attr( $size["width"] ); ?>" alt="<?php bloginfo("name"); ?>"  class="img-fluid">
                                </a>
                            <?php } elseif (get_theme_mod( 'dealsdot_logo_text' )) { ?>
                                <a class="nav-brand text" href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( "/" ) ); ?>" title="<?php bloginfo("name"); ?>">
                                    <span><?php echo esc_html(get_theme_mod( 'dealsdot_logo_text' )); ?></span>
                                </a>
                            <?php } else { ?>
                                <a class="nav-brand text" href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( "/" ) ); ?>" title="<?php bloginfo("name"); ?>">
                                    <span><?php esc_html_e("Dealsdot","dealsdot"); ?></span>
                                </a>
                            <?php } ?>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    
                    <?php $searchbutton = get_theme_mod('dealsdot_header_search_button','0'); ?>
                    <?php if($searchbutton == '1'){ ?>
                    <div class="col-lg-5 col-md-4 col-sm-5 col-xs-12 top-search-holder"> 
                        <?php get_template_part( 'includes/header/search' ); ?>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-5 col-md-5 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 navmenu"> 
                    <?php } else { ?>
                    <div class="col-lg-10 col-md-10 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 navmenu"> 
                    <?php } ?>
                        <div class="yamm navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
                            <div class="navbar-header">
                                <button data-target="#mc-horizontal-menu-collapse" data-toggle="collapse" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" type="button"> 
                                <span class="sr-only"><?php esc_html_e('Toggle navigation','dealsdot'); ?></span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> </button>
                            </div>
                            <div class="nav-bg-class">
                                <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="mc-horizontal-menu-collapse">
                                    <div class="nav-outer">
                                        <?php 
                                        wp_nav_menu(array(
                                        "theme_location" => "main-menu",
                                        "container" => "",
                                        "fallback_cb" => "show_top_menu",
                                        "menu_id" => "",
                                        "menu_class" => "nav navbar-nav",
                                        "echo" => true,
                                        "walker" => new dealsdot_description_walker(),
                                        "depth" => 0 
                                        )); 
                                        ?>
                                    
                                        <div class="clearfix"></div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <?php get_template_part( 'includes/header/cart' ); ?>
                        
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>      
        </div>
    </header>
<div class="body-content" id="top-banner-and-menu">
```

I also add the main.css of the header:

```
/*===================================================================================*/
/* Header
/*===================================================================================*/
header{
    background: #fdd922;
}

.main-header {
  padding:0px 0px 0px 0px;
  background: #ee4054;
  height:74px;
  width:100%;

}
.main-header .logo-holder {
  margin-top:8px;
  line-height:53px;

}

.main-header .logo-holder .logo img { }

.navbar-default {background:none; border:none; font-family: 'Barlow', sans-serif; color:#fff; margin-bottom:0px; margin-top:10px; float:left; margin-bottom:15px;}
.main-header .navbar-default .navbar-collapse .navbar-nav > li {margin-top:5px}
.main-header .navbar-default .navbar-collapse .navbar-nav > li > a {color:#fff; font-size:16px; font-weight:600; padding:12px 15px;}
.main-header .navbar-default .navbar-collapse .navbar-nav > li > a:hover {background:#fff; border-radius:999px; color:#ee4054}
.navbar-collapse {padding:0}
.navmenu {padding-left:0px}

.top-banner img {box-shadow:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) 0px 1px 2px 0px; border-radius:5px}
.slider-section {background:#fff; position:relative; overflow:hidden; border-radius: 4px; box-shadow: 0 1px 2px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.2);}

.top-search-holder {}
.main-header .top-search-holder .contact-row {
  line-height: 20px;
  color: #9b9b9b;
}
.main-header .top-search-holder .contact-row .phone {
  margin: 0 23px 0 0;
  border-right: 1px solid #E2E2E2;
  padding-right: 35px;
}
.main-header .top-search-holder .contact-row .icon {
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 23px;
  margin: 0 8px 0 0;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.main-header .top-search-holder .search-area {
  -webkit-border-radius: 0px;
  -moz-border-radius: 0px;
  border-radius: 0px;
  margin:14px 0px;
  background:#fff;
  border-radius:999px;
}

.main-header .top-search-holder .search-area .search-field {
  border: medium none;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px 0 0 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px 0 0 5px;
  border-radius:999px;
  padding:13px 19px;
  width: 67%;
  font-family: 'Barlow', sans-serif;
  font-size:14px;
}
.main-header .top-search-holder .search-area .categories-filter {
  border-right: 1px solid #E0E0E0;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 35px;
  background: #f6f6f6;
  border-radius:999px 0px 0px 999px;
}
.main-header .top-search-holder .search-area .categories-filter a {
  padding: 0 20px;
  color: #666;
  font-size: 14px;
}
.main-header .top-search-holder .search-area .categories-filter a .caret {
  margin-left: 15px;
  color: #a0a0a0;
}
.main-header .top-search-holder .search-area .categories-filter .dropdown-menu {
  -moz-box-shadow: none;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  border: 1px solid #e1e1e1;
  padding: 12px 17px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0px;
  -moz-border-radius: 0px;
  border-radius: 0px;
}
.main-header .top-search-holder .search-area .categories-filter .dropdown-menu li {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.main-header .top-search-holder .search-area .categories-filter .dropdown-menu li a {
  padding: 0px;
}
.main-header .top-search-holder .search-area .categories-filter .dropdown-menu li a:hover,
.main-header .top-search-holder .search-area .categories-filter .dropdown-menu li a:focus {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
.main-header .top-search-holder .search-area .categories-filter .dropdown-menu li.menu-header {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  line-height: 30px;
}
.main-header .top-search-holder .search-area .search-button {
    border-radius: 999px;
    display: inline-block;
    float: right;
    margin: 4px 5px;
    padding: 10px 12px;
    text-align: center;
    background: #ee4054;

}
.main-header .top-search-holder .search-area .search-button:after {
  color: #fff;
  content: "\f002";
  font-family: fontawesome;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 16px;

}
.cnt-home .header-style-1.header-style-2 .header-nav .navbar-default {
  background: #404040;
}
.top-cart-row {
  padding-top:8px;
  padding-left:0px;
  float:right
}
.top-cart-row .dropdown-cart {
  float: right;
}

.top-cart-row .dropdown-cart img {width:100%}

.top-cart-row .dropdown-cart .lnk-cart {
  padding: 0px;
  background: #56cb60;
  border-top:2px #d8283c solid;
  border-radius:999px;
  display: inline-block;
  color: #fff;
  margin-top: 5px;
}
.top-cart-row .dropdown-cart .lnk-cart .items-cart-inner {
  position: relative;
}
.top-cart-row .dropdown-cart .lnk-cart .items-cart-inner .total-price-basket {
    padding: 12px 25px 13px 15px;
    font-family: 'Barlow', sans-serif;
    float: left;
    letter-spacing: 0.5px;
    font-weight:600;
    font-size:16px
}
.top-cart-row .dropdown-cart .lnk-cart .items-cart-inner .basket {
  float: left;
  padding: 15px 20px 13px 25px;
}

.top-cart-row .dropdown-cart .lnk-cart .items-cart-inner .basket i {font-size:16px}

.top-cart-row .dropdown-cart .lnk-cart .items-cart-inner .basket-item-count {
-webkit-border-radius: 100px;
    -moz-border-radius: 100px;
    border-radius: 100px;
    height: 20px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 49px;
    top: 14px;
    width: 20px;
    background: #fff;
    color: #0f6cb2;
    font-size: 11px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 20px;
}
.top-cart-row .dropdown-cart .dropdown-menu {
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  float: right;
  left: auto;
  min-width: 0;
  padding: 24px 22px;
  right: 0;
  width: 230px;
  -moz-box-shadow: none;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 2px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.2);
  border:none
}

.top-cart-row .dropdown-cart .dropdown-menu .col-xs-7 {padding-left:0px}

.top-cart-row .dropdown-cart .dropdown-menu .cart-item.product-summary .name {
  font-size: 13px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  margin-top: 0px;
  line-height: 19px;
}
.top-cart-row .dropdown-cart .dropdown-menu .cart-item.product-summary .name a {
  color: #666666;
}
.top-cart-row .dropdown-cart .dropdown-menu .cart-item.product-summary .price {
  font-weight: 700;
}
.top-cart-row .dropdown-cart .dropdown-menu .cart-item.product-summary .action {
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 15px;
  right: 8px;
  top: 8px;
}
.top-cart-row .dropdown-cart .dropdown-menu .cart-item.product-summary .action a {
  color: #898989;
}
.top-cart-row .dropdown-cart .dropdown-menu .cart-total .text {
  font-size: 13px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  color: #666666;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
.top-cart-row .dropdown-cart .dropdown-menu .cart-total .price {
  font-weight: 700;
}

.fl-links {
    float: left;
    background:none;
    border-left:1px solid hsla(0,0%,100%,.2);

}
.fl-links .clicker {
    padding: 0px 13px;
    line-height: 55px;
    height: 55px;
    display: block;

    
}
.fl-links > .no-js:hover > .clicker {
    padding: 0px 13px;
    line-height: 55px;
    height: 55px;
    color: #fff;
    background:#0e72c2

}
.fl-links .clicker:before {
    content: '\f0c9';
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    font-size: 16px;
    padding-left: 4px;
    padding-top: 2px;
    margin-right: 6px;
    height: 40px;
    cursor: pointer;
    color:#fff;
    
    
}
.fl-links .links {
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    font-family:'Barlow', sans-serif
}
.fl-links .links li {
    font-size: 13px;
    padding-top: 2px;
    padding-bottom: 2px;
    letter-spacing: 0.5px;
    padding-left: 0px
}
.fl-links .links li:last-child {
    border: none
}

.fl-links .no-js .fl-nav-links {
    background: #202020;
    background-repeat: repeat;
    background-position: 0 0;
    padding: 15px;
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 25px;
    z-index: 100;
    border-top: 0;
    width: 150px;
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0;
    right: 15px;
    margin-top: -2px;
    transform: scale(0) rotate(0deg);
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
    visibility: hidden;
}
.fl-links .no-js:hover .fl-nav-links {
    background: #fff;
    background-repeat: repeat;
    background-position: 0 0;
    padding: 15px 20px;
    margin: 0;
    width: 150px;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 25px;
    z-index: 100;
    border-top: 0;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    right:15px;
    margin-top: -2px;
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.0) rotate(0deg);
    transform: scale(1.0) rotate(0deg);
    box-shadow:0 2px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
    border-radius:3px
}

.fl-links .no-js:hover .fl-nav-links:before {
    content: "";
    clear: both;
    display: block;
    width: 0;
    border-bottom: 8px solid #fff;
    border-left: 8px solid transparent;
    border-right: 8px solid transparent;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: -23px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 99;
    float:right

}

.fl-links .no-js:hover .fl-nav-links .links a {
    color: #555;
    letter-spacing:normal
}
.fl-links .no-js:hover .fl-nav-links .links a:hover {
    color: #0f6cb2;
    letter-spacing:normal
}

.header-style-1 .header-nav .navbar-default {
  border: medium none;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 0;
  border-radius: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  margin: 0;
  min-height:auto;
}
.header-style-1 .header-nav .navbar-default .navbar-collapse {
  padding: 0;
}
.header-style-1 .header-nav .navbar-default .navbar-collapse .navbar-nav > li.active > a {
  color: #fff;
}
.navbar-nav {float:none}

.special-menu {float:right}
.special-menu a {color:#ffdd35!important; border:none!important; padding-right:0px!important} 
.special-menu a:hover{ background:none!important; color:#fff!important}

.header-style-1 .header-nav .navbar-default .navbar-collapse .navbar-nav > li > a {
  background: none repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-family: 'Barlow', sans-serif;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height:normal;
  padding: 18px 18px;
  -webkit-transitio: all 0.2s linear 0s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.2s linear 0s;
  -o-transition: all 0.2s linear 0s;
  transition: all 0.2s linear 0s;
  font-weight:500;
  letter-spacing:normal;
      position: relative;

}
.header-style-1 .header-nav .navbar-default .navbar-collapse .navbar-nav > li .menu-label {
  position: absolute;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  top: -10px;
  display: inline;
  padding: 4px 8px;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 10px;
  font-family:'Barlow', sans-serif;
  right: 23px;
  line-height: normal;
  letter-spacing:1px;
  border-radius:2px
}
.header-style-1 .header-nav .navbar-default .navbar-collapse .navbar-nav > li .menu-label:after {
  border-width: 6px 7px 0 6px;
  right: 18px;
  top: 90%;
  border-style: solid;
  content: "";
  display: block;
  height: 0;
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
  -o-transitio: all 0.3s ease 0s;
  transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
  width: 0;
  z-index: 100;
  
}
.header-style-1 .header-nav .navbar-default .navbar-collapse .navbar-nav > li .menu-label:before {
  right: 18px;
  top: 90%;
}
.header-style-1 .header-nav .navbar-default .navbar-collapse .navbar-nav > li .menu-label.new-menu {
  background: #f1c40f;
}
.header-style-1 .header-nav .navbar-default .navbar-collapse .navbar-nav > li .menu-label.new-menu:after {
  border-color: #f1c40f rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
.header-style-1 .header-nav .navbar-default .navbar-collapse .navbar-nav > li .menu-label.new-menu:before {
  border-color: #f1c40f rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
.header-style-1 .header-nav .navbar-default .navbar-collapse .navbar-nav > li .menu-label.hot-menu {
  background: #ff7878;
}
.header-style-1 .header-nav .navbar-default .navbar-collapse .navbar-nav > li .menu-label.hot-menu:after {
  border-color: #ff7878 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
.header-style-1 .header-nav .navbar-default .navbar-collapse .navbar-nav > li .menu-label.hot-menu:before {
  border-color: #ff7878 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
.header-style-2 {
  /*margin-bottom:10px;*/
}
.header-style-2 .header-nav {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) !important;
}
.header-style-2 .header-nav .navbar-default .nav-bg-class {
  -webkit-border-radius: 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 0;
  border-radius: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.header-style-2 .header-nav .navbar-default .nav-bg-class .navbar-collapse .navbar-nav > li > a {
  color: #555;
}
.header-style-2 .header-nav .navbar-default .nav-bg-class .navbar-collapse .navbar-nav > li > a:hover,
.header-style-2 .header-nav .navbar-default .nav-bg-class .navbar-collapse .navbar-nav > li > a:focus {
  color: #fff;
}
.header-style-2 .header-nav .navbar-default .nav-bg-class .navbar-collapse .navbar-nav > li.open > a {
  color: #fff;
}
.header-style-3 .header-nav {
  background: #202020 !important;
  border: medium none;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 0;
  border-radius: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.header-style-3 .header-nav .navbar-default .navbar-collapse .navbar-nav > li > a {
  color: #fff;
}
.header-style-3 .header-nav .navbar-default .navbar-collapse .navbar-nav > li > a:hover,
.header-style-3 .header-nav .navbar-default .navbar-collapse .navbar-nav > li > a:focus {
  color: #fff;
}
.header-style-3 .header-nav .yamm .dropdown-menu {
  top: 62px;
}
.yamm .nav,
.yamm .collapse,
.yamm .dropup,
.yamm .dropdown {
  position: static;
}
.yamm .dropdown-menu {
  left:auto;
  top: 98% ;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0px;
  -moz-border-radius: 0px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border:none;
  padding:0px;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
}

.yamm .dropdown-menu .custom-banner a {padding:0px}
.yamm .dropdown-menu .banner-image { margin-bottom:0px}

.navbar-nav .open a{
    float: none;
    background:#fff;
    color:#ee4054;
    border-radius:999px;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.open>a {background:#fff; color:#ee4054!important;}

.yamm .dropdown-menu .yamm-content {
  padding: 10px 20px;
  border-radius:10px;

}
.sidebar .side-menu .nav > li > a:hover{background:none;}

.yamm .dropdown-menu .yamm-content .col-menu {min-width:150px}

.yamm .dropdown-menu .yamm-content .links li a {
  padding: 6px 0px;
    font-size:14px;
    color:#565656;
    
}


.yamm .dropdown-menu h2 {
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #555;
  margin-top: 0px;
  font-weight:600
}
.yamm .dropdown-menu li {
  line-height:normal;
  padding: 0px 0px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
  transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
}
.yamm .dropdown-menu li a {
  color: #3D3D3D;
  line-height: normal;
  text-transform: none ;
  display: block;
  padding: 8px 16px;
}
.yamm .dropdown-menu li a:hover,
.yamm .dropdown-menu li a:focus {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  margin-left: 0px;
}
.yamm .dropdown-menu .text {
  font-size: 13px;
  line-height: 20px;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 0px;
  top: 73px;
}
.yamm .dropdown.yamm-fw .dropdown-menu {
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
.cnt-home .header-style-1.header-style-2 .header-nav .navbar .navbar-nav > li.active > a,
.cnt-homepage .header-style-1.header-style-2 .header-nav .navbar .navbar-nav > li.active > a {
  color: #fff;
}
.cnt-home .header-style-1.header-style-2 .header-nav .navbar-default {
  background: #404040;
}
.cnt-home .header-style-1.header-style-2 .header-nav .navbar-default .nav-bg-class {
  border: none;
}
.cnt-home .header-style-1.header-style-2 .header-nav .navbar-default .nav-bg-class .navbar-collapse .navbar-nav > li > a {
  color: #fff;
}
.cnt-homepage .header-style-2 .header-nav .navbar-default {
  background: #fff;
}
.cnt-homepage .header-style-2 .header-nav .navbar-default .nav-bg-class {
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 0 3px #F6F6F6 inset;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 3px #F6F6F6 inset;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 3px #F6F6F6 inset;
}
.header-nav .navbar-default .dropdown .dropdown-menu.pages .links > li {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #eaeaea;
  padding: 5px 0;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
  transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
}
.header-nav .navbar-default .dropdown .dropdown-menu.pages .links > li:last-child {
  border-bottom: none;
}
.header-nav .navbar-default .dropdown .dropdown-menu.pages .links > li > a {
  line-height: 26px;
  padding: 0px;
}
.header-nav .navbar-default .dropdown .dropdown-menu.pages .links > li > a:hover,
.header-nav .navbar-default .dropdown .dropdown-menu.pages .links > li > a:focus {
  margin-left: 0px;
}
```

Comment: Without a reproducible demo, no one can really help you with this.